# How to pass inequal operators for parameters in SQL Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a stored query below in Access call "1PreviousEWBS":

```
SELECT f.ewbs AS EWBS, SUM(f.[total hours]) AS [Total Hours], SUM(f.[total cost]) AS [Total Cost],                                 T.description AS Activity, T.AWBS AS AWBS
FROM FindHrCostByEWBS AS f, AllProjectsCodes AS T
WHERE (f.project)=Forms!x!cboProjects 
And f.[period end date]<Forms!x!cboDate     
And f.ewbs=T.oldewbs     
GROUP BY f.ewbs,T.description, T.AWBS;
```

Bascially I wrote this so users can use the combo box to select their data.

But now, I am curious to see how can i set the parameters directly through VBA. I had something like this set up.

```
Sub TestSeePreviousData

     Dim rS As DAO.Recordset
     Dim db As DAO.Database
     Dim queryDef As DAO.queryDef

    Dim ProjectNumber As String
    Dim FiscalDate As Date
    FiscalDate = #4/25/2014#

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set queryDef = db.QueryDefs("1PreviousEWBS")

    'Parameter 0 is to input the Project number
     queryDef.Parameters(0) = "173221"
     'Parameter 1 is to give the fiscal period end date
     queryDef.Parameters(1) = "'" & FiscalDate & "


   Set rS = queryDef.OpenRecordset

    Do While Not rS.EOF
        'The lines for 1PreviousEWBS
        Debug.Print rS.Fields("EWBS") & vbTab & rS.Fields("AWBS") & vbTab & rS.Fields("Total Hours") & vbTab &     rS.Fields("Total Cost")


        rS.MoveNext
    Loop


End Sub
```

My problem is, I want to recreate the initial "less than" condition, ie

f.[period end date] < [Input Date],  and this:

queryDef.Parameters(1) < "'" & FiscalDate & "'"

does not work, it returns an error message of "Invalid Use of Properties"

my question is, how can i show inequal condition when setting parameters for SQL in vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the comparison operator should be hard-coded in the QueryDef SQL, and the Parameter which represents the fiscal date is the only one which needs to be set at runtime.  Have you tried that?

And not sure if your query 1PreviousEWBS is using the same exact SQL you listed, but you would change the Form reference (Forms!x!cboDate) to a standard parameter reference - [pFiscalDate] - for example.

Your code should look to replace [pFiscalDate] at run-time, and the < should be part of the QueryDef code.

Comment: hi @user3618839    I think the problem is coming down to the "DIM FiscalDate as Date" . i think there is a conversion problem when i set it as #4/25/2014# , and then setting it later on as '#4/25/2014#' .

Comment: further to your point, what i don't understand is, if the query def already has the parameter requirement hardcoded in. ie. f.[period end date] < cboBox value. Then how come I still get prompted to input a parameter value? couldnt I just assign in the procedure, cboBox = [01/13/2013] , then querydef.openrecordset?

Comment: hi tyrion.  i don't quite understand your first comment, to be honest.  there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the dimensioning of FiscalDate as a date nor the setting of it to #4/25/2014#.  if you are doubtful, comment out everything after it and run it; i am sure it won't break.

Comment: to your second question, what is cboBox?  is it a control on a form somewhere?  and where does your TestSeePreviousData subroutine live?  behind a form?  or a publicly accessible module?

Comment: whenever access cannot resolve otherwise sytactically correct SQL from a QueryDef at runtime, it considers the part it can't resolve a parameter.  it defaults to a bring up an input box and interrogate the user for a value.  in this case, if it can't resolve cboBox, in this case, for whatever reason, it will ask you for it.  if it is a control on a form, the QueryDef probably can't find it because your control doesn't have a fully-qualified reference (Forms!MyForm!cboBox).

Comment: hi VBlades:  You're right. the comparison operator should be coded in the SQL. and the pFiscalDate value is assigned at run time. This is the correct answer to my question. I took a step back and used your suggestion on a simpler query , and it worked.

Comment: The reason why i think this query was acting strange based on the given parameter was because this query JOINS tables with other queries. So i suspect i'd need to define their parameters as well. that will be a question for another time

Comment: hi tyrion.  it can be confusing, so glad that all worked out for you.  just remember:

Comment: that querydefs.parameter(0) < x makes no sense in vba; you are looking to assign a value to the parameter and not compare it at that point.  also, i'm pretty sure the join in the query should not affect the parameters, but like you did, break it down to its most elementary parts and build on that.  if the joins do give you problems, maybe switch your code to an inner join from the cross join with where clause you have now.  the jet engine is not super smart, in my experience, maybe that is giving it issues.  good luck!